# FindRoot on a large system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, export

I need to solve, numerically, a very large system of equations (Logit-type). The system has one parameter $d$ which is numerically defined in order to find the solution.

My code works, but it requires 11 minutes to run. I want:

1. To increase the efficiency of my code (I have to estimate also a different "pay" function which will generate around 10.000 equations instead of the actual 250).
2. I want Mathematica to run my program across many values of $d$ (user-defined).
3. I want Mathematica to save solutions for each $d$ in a dataset which can be exported to *Stata* for a maximum likelihood estimation (my task will be to find the parameter $d$ which better fit my data). Or, maybe, I can import my observations in Mathematica for the maximum likelihood estimation? What's best?

Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[qmax, qmax2, pay]
qmax[h_] := Floor[8 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[h]];
qmax2[h_, q_] := Min[qmax[h], (q - 1)];
pay[h_, q_] := (32 - q^2/(4 h))*(1/10)*Sum[
   Sum[Symbol["t" <> ToString[t] <> "q" <> ToString[s]], {s, 0, qmax2[t, q]}]+ 
   If[q <= qmax[t], 0.5*Symbol["t" <> ToString[t] <> "q" <> ToString[q]], 0],
   {t, 1, 10}];

equations = Flatten@Table[
  Table[
  Symbol["t" <> ToString[h] <> "q" <> ToString[q]] == 
  Exp[d*pay[h,q]]/Sum[Exp[d*pay[h, s]], {s, 0, qmax[h]}],
  {q, 0, qmax[h]}],
  {h, 1, 10}];

vars = Flatten[Table[
  {Symbol["t" <> ToString[h] <> "q" <> ToString[q]], 0.01}, 
  {h,1, 10}, {q, 0, qmax[h]}], 1];

d = 1;
FindRoot[equations, vars]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to work towards your goals? If you encounter *specific* problems, people here will be able to help. However, as it is currently written, yours is not a request for help, but unfortunately it rather reads like a job advertisement. The issue is that any contributions towards your problem would likely only help this specific case, and not be of general value to this community.

Comment: A general way to speed up `FindRoot` is to start with a good guess.  Do you know more about the solution than 0.01 for each component?  When you do get to varying the parameter `d`, try using the previous `d`'s answer as an initial guess for the next root -- or get more sophisticated with linear or quadratic extrapolation.

Comment: This `equations = Total[Abs[Flatten@Table[Table[Symbol["t"<>ToString[h]<>"q" <>ToString[q]]*Sum[Exp[d*pay[h, s]], {s,0,qmax[h]}]-Exp[d*pay[h,q]], {q,0,qmax[h]}], {h,1,10}]]] //. {0.5*xxx_+0.5*yyy_->0.5*(xxx+yyy), 2*xxx_+2*yyy_->2*(xxx+yyy)}; vars=Flatten[Table[{Symbol["t"<>ToString[h]<>"q"<>ToString[q]]}, {h,1,10}, {q,0,qmax[h]}]]; d=1; AbsoluteTiming[NMinimize[equations, vars]]` takes about 30 seconds to find an approximate solution. That only times the solve. Can you confirm that this works? Can you show a problem with 1000 equations? Can you give a list of example d values?